# Twitter OAuth iOS6

Tags: objective-c, ios6, twitter-oauth

How to use OAuth in a new iOS App in 6?
Access Token,
Access Secret Token.
and appears as the identifier of App, for example http://ilearntutorials.files.wordpress.com/2012/11/captura-de-tela-2012-11-04-c3a0s-14-34-39.png